# Are there any benefits to starting kdm as daemon?

Tags: linux, x-server, kdm, arch-linux, display-manager

I've configured my kdm to start via inittab method.

I've done it following the steps at [Display Manager - ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Display_Manager). There is also a described method on how to start kdm as daemon. But i can't find any reason for starting kdm via inittab or as a daemon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main benefit to starting it as a daemon is that you can stop it.  You might want to do this if, for example, something goes wrong with your X install.  You might want to stop it in order to fix something that it better done without X running.

If you kill kdm launched by inittab, init will simply respawn it.  If you stop a daemon, it remains stopped until you restart it.

This will only be a benefit for you if this scenario occurs, so I'd stick with your current configuration until you get into a situation that warrants changing it.